# bootstrap 3 delete image padding navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would remove the padding and the margin of the facebook logo in the menu. I tried putting a class `<a class="fblogo"` ... and change your style `.navbar .nav .navbar-nav> li> a.fblogo` making 0 the margin and padding but does not work. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: show some demo please

Comment: Some demo please in Fiddle, we are not Nostradamus. May be you need making margin and padding 0 for image and not <a>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PLMCv/

Comment: i think solved. http://jsfiddle.net/PLMCv/2/

Comment: No idea. What problem you had and now what you resolved? Anyway it is fixed. fine.

Comment: To add a bigger logo and the height of the menu does not change